# CMD File not deleting when the file has spaces

Tags: batch-file, cmd

long time learner, first time poster. So i was tasked to find a way to be able to delete a file based off of date. the cmd/batch file should read todays date, look at the designated directory and tell you what to delete. I have borrowed a great deal from other posts here and even added a "choice" option just to be safe. The batch file will read all files in the directory and list if it should be deleted or kept. then it will ask are you sure you want to delete. if "y" is selected then it should delete the file but whenever it tries it says the file cannot be found. I know it must be because of the spaces in the file name. When i rename the files and remove the spaces it deletes them just fine. Im sorry if im all over the place, any help would be much appreciated. hereis what i have so far

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set day=86400
set /a year=day*365
set /a strip=day*7
set dSource=I:\Test

call :epoch %date%
set /a slice=epoch-strip

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d-h-s /b /s %dSource%') do (
call :epoch %%~tf
if !epoch! LEQ %slice% (echo DELETE %%f ^(%%~tf^)) ELSE echo keep %%f ^(%%~tf^)
)

echo/
if exist "%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe" goto UseChoice

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:UseSetPrompt
set "UserChoice=N"
set /P "UserChoice=Are you sure [Y/N]? "
set "UserChoice=!UserChoice: =!"
if /I "!UserChoice!" == "N" endlocal & goto :EOF
if /I not "!UserChoice!" == "Y" goto UseSetPrompt
endlocal
goto Continue

:UseChoice
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C YN /N /M "Are you sure [Y/N]? "
if errorlevel 2 goto :EOF

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d-h-s /b /s %dSource%') do (
call :epoch %%~tf
if !epoch! LEQ %slice% del /f %%f ^(%%~tf^)
)

PAUSE
exit /b 0

rem Args[1]: Year-Month-Day
:epoch
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=-;+^_?" %%d in ("echo %1") do set Years=%%d& set Months=%%e& set Days=%%f
if "!Months:~0,1!"=="0" set Months=!Months:~1,1!
if "!Days:~0,1!"=="0" set Days=!Days:~1,1!
set /a Days=Days*day
set /a _months=0
set i=1&& for %%m in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do if !i! LSS !Months! (set /a _months=!_months! + %%m*day&& set /a i+=1)
set /a Months=!_months!
set /a Years=(Years-1970)*year
set /a Epoch=Years+Months+Days
endlocal& set Epoch=%Epoch%
exit /b 0
```

Comment: "Quotes" are always your best friend.  Use them always.

Comment: `del /f "%%f"` should do. What's  `^(%%~tf^)` supposed to do?

Comment: `del /f "%%~f"` This removes quotes from the variable if it has quotes then puts quotes preventing the spaces from being expanded. Like @Stephan I am intrigued by what `^(%%~tf^)` is supposed to be...

Comment: @Stephan Thank you for your suggestion. Deleting ^(%%~tf^) and adding "" worked. What ^(%%~tf^) does is read out the entire file in the ifrst section when it tells you what to keep. I didnt think that having it in the actual deletion section would complicate things. but thank you for telling me to delete them.